# Python program converted to exe with pyinstaller isn't working in SOME pcs

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, pyinstaller, exe

My exe file is working fine in 3 computers and a virtual machine but isn't working in my company computer.

[Black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7A8h.png)

This black screen stays for ever.

The program has to output a simple question: Idioma / Lenguage ? (esp/eng)
this is the first part of my code:

```
import mkdir

print('Idioma / Lenguage ? (esp/eng) ')
lang = input()
mkdir('utils')
f = open("utils/specs.py", "w")
f.write("lang = '" + lang + "'")
f.close()
```

Any idea what may be going on?

PS: The command i'm using for pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller ./iwom_automator.py --onefile --icon=logo_iwom.ico
```

Comment: There are chances that your exe is being blocked by firewall at your organisation. Try checking the logs for the same

Comment: And also check the systems for 32-bit or 64-bit OS. May be your company's computer is of 32-bit and the other machines where you previously tested were of 64-bit.

Comment: @deep Hi thx for your reply all the tested computers ar 64-bit systems and my firewall isn't blocking anything. Thats why i'm so confused.

Comment: Try creating and running a 32-bit EXE on all those system. Higher chances that 32-bit EXE will work on all those machines.

Comment: @Deep okey I will try. Thx anyways!